# JavaScript: Replace a repeated variable character in a with a "*"

Tags: javascript, regex, methods

I'm trying to write a function that replaces with an asterisk repetitions of a single character string found within a string (of any length), for example, if the function arguments are `"banana","a"` it should return:
`ban*n*` *-- and case is irrelevant here.*

At present I'm attempting to achieve this with .replace and a regex.

```
function charReplace (string, x) {
  string.replace(/x{2,}/gi, "*");
  return string;
};
console.log(charReplace("banana","a")); // output banana
console.log(charReplace("banana","n")); // output banana
console.log(charReplace("Apple","p")); // output Apple
```

I also tried adding the repeat operator (+), but that threw an error.

```
function charReplace (string, x) {
  string.replace(/x+{2,}/gi, "*"); 
  at charReplace
  return string;
};
console.log(charReplace("banana","a")); 
console.log(charReplace("banana","n")); 
console.log(charReplace("Apple","p"));
```

Error: `// Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /x+{2,}/: Nothing to repeat at charReplace`

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and fix the desired outputs you added as comments in the code, so that it's more clear what you want in each case? Also, I keep fixing your `"ban*n*"` because you have "bn*n*", but it always gets overwritten 

Comment: The forum markdown rules keep messing with my input. I'm trying to get to this result:
 
`ban*n*`

Comment: Do you realize it saying match "x", it is not the variable?

Comment: @blex I've been trying to do that myself but but the forum keeps overriding my updates, too, and will not permit me to repost once I've edited it. 

`ban*n*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Version 1: case sensitive

You could:

1. Split the string on the character
2. Join the string back together with `*`
3. Replace the first `*` with the character

```js
function charReplace (string, x) {
  return string.split(x).join('*').replace('*', x);
};

console.log(charReplace("banana", "a")); // output ban*n*
console.log(charReplace("banana", "n")); // output bana*a
console.log(charReplace("Apple",  "p")); // output Ap*le
```

#### Version 2: case-insensitive

You can use the `RegExp` constructor to use a variable in your regex:

```js
function charReplace (string, x) {
  let isFirstMatch = true;
  return string.replace(new RegExp(`(${x})`, "gi"), (char) => {
    if (isFirstMatch) {
      isFirstMatch = false;
      return char;
    }
    return '*';
  });
};

console.log(charReplace("banana", "a")); // output ban*n*
console.log(charReplace("banana", "n")); // output bana*a
console.log(charReplace("Apple",  "p")); // output Ap*le
console.log(charReplace("ApPle",  "p")); // output Ap*le
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I never would've thought of this simple solution. FYI, I'm a coding student, just learning my way around JS. Everyday is like starting over for me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @bobbieganujsh Cool! Careful though, that first version was case sensitive (would not replace any uppercase "A" if you give it a lowercase "a". I've added a second version handling that case

Comment: Excellent and duly noted. Appreciate the additional example giving case a nod.